# Rails 3: Share active record sessions between two apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have two rails apps, running on the same domain.  They both require some knowledge of the current user.  Previously we'd been handling this with localStorage, but security concerns have led us to transition to database session storage.

Each app has it's own database (and will, for the time being).  Is there a way for me to tell app B to use the session store for app A?  Can I define a database and table relationship somewhere for this?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection should help. Assuming your model name is Session on application B, try something like this:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :adapter => 'mysql2', :database => 'database_of_app_a', :host => 'localhost', :username => 'database_of_app_a_username', :password => 'database_of_app_a_password'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully doing this between a Rails 3 and a Rails 4 app on the same host with identical database setups.

They should have the same secret key in initializers/secret_token.rb

```
AppB::Application.config.secret_key_base = "same-as-app-a"
```

and table name set in initializers/session_store.rb

```
AppB::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store

ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.table_name = 'app_a_sessions'
```

The Rails 4 app doesn't even have a login page - it redirects to the Rails 3 app's login page and it handles authentication for both of them.